# Strange output can't solve

Tags: java, arraylist, output

I am simply trying to print an ArrayList using a name class I made.

Here is the method

```
private static ArrayList createActorList() {
    ArrayList<Name> actors = new ArrayList<>();
    actors.add(new Name("Tom","Cruise"));
    actors.add(new Name("Sylvester","Stallone"));
    actors.add(new Name("Michael J.","Fox"));
    actors.add(new Name("Arnold","Schwarzenegger"));
    actors.add(new Name("Al","Pacino"));
    actors.add(new Name("Harrison","Ford"));
    actors.add(new Name("Matt","Dillon"));
    actors.add(new Name("Michael","Biehn"));
    actors.add(new Name("Emilio","Estevez"));
    actors.add(new Name("Rob","Lowe"));
    return actors;
}
```

Name class-The name class works fine for other programs printing the name when called.

```
    public class Name implements NameADT{
        public String first;
        public String last;
        public String natural;
        public String formal;
        public String check;

   public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
    first = firstName;
    last = lastName;

}

@Override
public String first() {
    return first;
}

@Override
public String last() {
    return last;
}

@Override
public String natural() {
    natural = first + " " + last;
    return natural;
}

@Override
public String formal() {
    formal = last + ", " + first;
    return formal;
}
```

Output when I print

The actors ...

```
simplethings.Name@7852e922<br>
simplethings.Name@4e25154f<br>
simplethings.Name@70dea4e<br>
simplethings.Name@5c647e05<br>
simplethings.Name@33909752<br>
simplethings.Name@55f96302<br>
simplethings.Name@3d4eac69<br>
simplethings.Name@42a57993<br>
simplethings.Name@75b84c92<br>
simplethings.Name@6bc7c054<br>
```

Comment: override toString() to return the firstName + " " + lastName

Answer (score -1):

Your problem lies in how Java stores objects (non-primitive data types). In short, a variable that does not store a primitive data type (`int`s, `double`s, `float`s, etc) only hold the address to where the actual data is stored. This means the variable only holds a *reference* to the object in memory, not the object itself.

That is what you are seeing when you try to print out the `Name` object (the address in your computer's memory where the actual instance is stored).

To solve this, you can override the `toString()` method of `Object`, which is implicitly called to convert to object to a string for printing. In your `Name` class, override it and return your first and last name:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return first + " " + last;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is because you are trying to print the object as it is. try using a list iterator and print the names. something like :

```
ListIterator<String> itr=al.listIterator();  
while(itr.hasNext()){ \\traversing elements in forward direction...
System.out.println(itr.next());  
 }
```

Comment: A better and more conventional way to solve this is to override the `toString` method of the `Name` object... this solution isn't very optimal and isn't fundamentally the best and encouraged practice